# I can't delete an item from a list in NHibernate

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

I have a problem deleting an item from a listing in C# and MySQL with NHibernate. I have the provider class that has a phone list, when I remove a phone from that list and call `session.Update()` it does not remove the phone, but if I edit the ones I have added and add new phones.

My mapping:

```
 public VendorMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id, x =>
                {
                x.Type(NHibernateUtil.Int32);
                x.Column("id");
                x.Generator(Generators.Native);
                });


            Bag(b => b.Phones, x =>
            {
                x.Inverse(true);
                x.Cascade(Cascade.All|Cascade.DeleteOrphans);
                x.Key(k => k.Column(col => col.Name("id_vendor")));
            }, Action => Action.OneToMany());



            Table("vendors");
        }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: yes, my code to update is:

`_transaction =  _session.BeginTransaction();` `_session.Update(vendor);`
 `_session.Flush();`
 `_transaction.Commit();`

Comment: Show the code where you delete the entity.

Comment: The call to Update() is not needed unless you have taken the object out from one NHibernate session and for some reason want to commit the update using a different session.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem.
In the handling of the telephone list.
I created a new phone list without the deleted phones and assigned them instead of removing the deleted phones from the original list.